# mySQL to PHP dynamic table

Tags: php, mysql

This question has been asked many times but I'm sorry I still can't make it work.
I have a simple mySQL DB like this table:

[image]

In this DB I have a column with people and 3 other columns that represent days - Day 1, Day 2 and Day 3.
The letter "M" means Morning and "A" Afternoon.
So I want to query this DB and ask: "Who was working Day 1 in the morning?" and it returns "John". 
I know how to do this query, but I don't know how to format the return.
Let's say that 3 people worked Day 1 morning (because the actual DB is bigger then this one) I want the HTML to return a 3 row table stating their names, but if only 2 persons worked Day one in the morning, it would return only a 2 row table stating their names.

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect(".",".",".");
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db("xbizh_14391723_horario", $con);

    $sql = "SELECT  `AM` FROM HORARIO WHERE  `1` ='N'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);


    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
        die($message);
     }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        print_r($row);
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Comment: cant able to understand your question

Comment: @NicoO's message means: you just posted your MySQL username & password to the internet. You should change it immediately.

Comment: What is `AM`? And when the column `1` does not hold a value `N`, how do you expect a resultset?

Comment: That's fine, it only accepts localhost connections and it's a free testing domain, so it's cool. 
Well by dynamic I mean the oposite of static.
I'll edit the question to be more specific...

Comment: You are practically there. I've posted an answer that should get you the rest of the way. If you have any questions about it, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are most of the way there already.

```
print("<table>");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    print("<tr><td>" . $row['name_field'] . "</td></tr>");
}

print("</table>");
```

You also need to make sure your query is returning the name field.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM HORARIO WHERE  `1` ='N'";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT `name_field` FROM HORARIO WHERE  `1` ='N'";
```

Comment: Thanks mate! After so many unapreciated comments this is finally an answer I can use!
Thanks a lot for your time. It worked like a charm!